# UITableview Selection Hide

Tags: iphone

I want to hide(or notshowing) Selected row in tableview....

i am using [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

But its doesnot work.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to remove it or deselect it? To remove it, you need to remove it from your datasource reference, then call

```
[myDelegate tableViewSelectionDidChange:NSTableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification];
```

More info is in the Table View programming guide:

http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Tasks/UsingTableDataSource.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000117